# Hydra disable interpretation of prefix argument

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, hydra

For a long time I've used a common emacs hydra to navigate expressions, along the lines of

```
(defhydra hydra-word (:color red) "word"
  ("M-f" forward-word)
  ("M-b" backward-word)
  ("f" forward-word)
  ("b" backward-word)
  ;; etc..
  )
```

But an annoying issue I always have: pressing a number is interpreted as a prefix argument when I always mean to simply insert a number. I looked through the hydra wiki, but couldn't find an answer to disable prefix interpretation. I know I can write a `("1" self-insert-command nil :exit t)` for each number, but that's dumb and results in a bunch of extra functions created.

How can I disable interpretation of prefix arg during an active hydra? And, I guess more generally is there a way to temporarily disable interpretation of prefix arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking through the code I found you can override hydras base map which is like `universal-argument-map`.  So, to implement the above with only <kbd>C-u</kbd> starting a prefix, but all numbers and `-` self-inserting, the following works

```
(defhydra hydra-word (:color red :base-map (make-sparse-keymap)) "word"
  ("M-f" forward-word)
  ("M-b" backward-word)
  ("f" forward-word)
  ("b" backward-word)
  ;; etc..
  )
```